# Reference Request: Implicit Difference Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, implicit-function

I know that there are some studies on implicit differential equations such as
$$ f(x, y, y') = 0. $$

I did some search but found very few results on the discrete version---implicit **difference** equations, such as
$$ f(k, x(k), x(k+1)) = 0. $$

Could you please recommend some introductions on **implicit difference equations**, if there is any?

Comment: Look at something called descriptor or singular systems.

Comment: @KBS I glanced over something about singular systems but I'm still not clear about how are they related with "implicit difference equations".

Comment: Perhaps glancing is not enough and a more thorough search is necessary. Such dynamical systems are represented by such implicit recurrence equations. So, yes they are related.